# Main method not found

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

When I try to excute the java class below (AuctionExample1.java), I got the following error :
"selection does not contain the main type"

Here is the java class :

```
package org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction;

/**
* A simple example showing how to create a bidder datacenter and a bidder broker 
* and start the auction.
* No VM is specified at all because no one wins he auction.
* 
* Created on 2011/9/9
*/
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Cloudlet;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.CloudletSchedulerTimeShared;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.DatacenterCharacteristics;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Host;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Log;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Pe;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Storage;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.UtilizationModel;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.UtilizationModelFull;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Vm;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmAllocationPolicySimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmSchedulerTimeShared;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.auctioneer.Auctioneer;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.bid.DatacenterBid;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.bid.DatacenterBrokerBid;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.bidder.BidderDatacenter;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.bidder.BidderDatacenterBroker;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.vm.DatacenterAbstractVm;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.auction.vm.VmCharacteristics;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.BwProvisionerSimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.PeProvisionerSimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.RamProvisionerSimple;

public class AuctionExample1 {

/** The cloudlet list. */
private static List<Cloudlet> cloudletList;

/** The vmlist. */
private static List<Vm> vmlist;

/**
 * Creates main() to run this example.
 *
 * @param args the args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Log.printLine("Starting AuctionExample1...");

    try {
        // First step: Initialize the CloudSim package. It should be called
        // before creating any entities.
        int num_user = 1; // number of cloud users
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        boolean trace_flag = false; // mean trace events

        // Initialize the CloudSim library
        CloudSim.init(num_user, calendar, trace_flag);
        Auctioneer.initAuctioneer();

        // Second step: Create Datacenters
        // Datacenters are the resource providers in CloudSim. We need at
        // list one of them to run a CloudSim simulation
        BidderDatacenter datacenter0 = createDatacenter("Datacenter_0");

        // Third step: Create Broker
        BidderDatacenterBroker broker = createBroker();
        int brokerId = broker.getId();

        // Fourth step: Create one virtual machine
        vmlist = new ArrayList<Vm>();

        // VM description
        int vmid = 0;
        int mips = 1000;  /*Youness: VM need  to  be  allocated  a  share  of  
        processing  power  on   Datacenter's  hosts.*/

        long size = 10000; // image size (MB) (Youness: virtual machine's image size)
        int ram = 512; // vm memory (MB)
        long bw = 1000;
        int pesNumber = 1; // number of cpus
        String vmm = "Xen"; // VMM name

        // create VM
        Vm vm = new Vm(vmid, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new                 CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());

        // add the VM to the vmList
        vmlist.add(vm);

        // Fifth step: Create one Cloudlet
        cloudletList = new ArrayList<Cloudlet>();

        // Cloudlet properties
        int id = 0;
        long length = 400000; //MI       cloudletLength
        long fileSize = 300;   //cloudletFileSize
        long outputSize = 300;  //cloudletOutputSize
        UtilizationModel utilizationModel = new UtilizationModelFull();

        Cloudlet cloudlet = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
        cloudlet.setUserId(brokerId);
        cloudlet.setVmId(vmid);//Youness: Bind cloudLet to a VM. If you do not do this, application assigns the first created VM for this cloudlet

        // add the cloudlet to the list
        cloudletList.add(cloudlet);

        // submit cloudlet list to the broker
        broker.submitCloudletList(cloudletList);


        DatacenterBrokerBid brokerBid = new DatacenterBrokerBid(broker.getId(), 0.0035);
        brokerBid.addVM(vm, 1);
        broker.submitBid(brokerBid);

        // Sixth step: Starts the simulation
        CloudSim.startSimulation();         

        CloudSim.stopSimulation();

        //Final step: Print results when simulation is over
        List<Cloudlet> newList = broker.getCloudletReceivedList();
        printCloudletList(newList);

        // Print the debt of each user to each datacenter
        datacenter0.printDebts();

        Log.printLine("AuctionExample1 finished!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.printLine("Unwanted errors happen");
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the datacenter.
 *
 * @param name the name
 *
 * @return the datacenter
 */
private static BidderDatacenter createDatacenter(String name) {

    // Here are the steps needed to create a PowerDatacenter:
    // 1. We need to create a list to store
    // our machine
    List<Host> hostList = new ArrayList<Host>();

    // 2. A Machine contains one or more PEs or CPUs/Cores.
    // In this example, it will have only one core.
    List<Pe> peList = new ArrayList<Pe>();

    int mips = 1000;

    // 3. Create PEs and add these into a list.
    peList.add(new Pe(0, new PeProvisionerSimple(mips))); // need to store Pe id and MIPS Rating

    // 4. Create Host with its id and list of PEs and add them to the list
    // of machines
    int hostId = 0;
    int ram = 2048; // host memory (MB)
    long storage = 1000000; // host storage
    int bw = 10000;

    Host host = new Host(
            hostId,
            new RamProvisionerSimple(ram),
            new BwProvisionerSimple(bw),
            storage,
            peList,
            new VmSchedulerTimeShared(peList)
        );
    hostList.add(host); // This is our machine

    // 5. Create a DatacenterCharacteristics object that stores the
    // properties of a data center: architecture, OS, list of
    // Machines, allocation policy: time- or space-shared, time zone
    // and its price (G$/Pe time unit).
    String arch = "x86"; // system architecture
    String os = "Linux"; // operating system
    String vmm = "Xen";
    double time_zone = 10.0; // time zone this resource located
    double cost = 3.0; // the cost of using processing in this resource
    double costPerMem = 0.05; // the cost of using memory in this resource
    double costPerStorage = 0.001; // the cost of using storage in this
                                    // resource
    double costPerBw = 0.0; // the cost of using bw in this resource
    LinkedList<Storage> storageList = new LinkedList<Storage>(); // we are not adding SAN
                                                // devices by now

    DatacenterCharacteristics characteristics = new DatacenterCharacteristics(
            arch, os, vmm, hostList, time_zone, cost, costPerMem,
            costPerStorage, costPerBw);

    // 6. Finally, we need to create a PowerDatacenter object.
    BidderDatacenter datacenter = null;
    try {
        datacenter = new BidderDatacenter(name, characteristics, new VmAllocationPolicySimple(hostList), storageList, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //TODO check if VM fits the host
    VmCharacteristics vmCharacteristics = new VmCharacteristics(
            arch, os, vmm, time_zone, cost, costPerMem,
            costPerStorage, costPerBw);
    DatacenterAbstractVm vm = new DatacenterAbstractVm(1000, 1, 512, 1000, 1000, vmCharacteristics);
    DatacenterBid bid = new DatacenterBid(datacenter.getId());
    bid.addVM(vm, 1);
    datacenter.submitBid(bid);

    return datacenter;
}

// We strongly encourage users to develop their own broker policies, to
// submit vms and cloudlets according
// to the specific rules of the simulated scenario
/**
 * Creates the broker.
 *
 * @return the datacenter broker
 */
private static BidderDatacenterBroker createBroker() {
    BidderDatacenterBroker broker = null;
    try {
        broker = new BidderDatacenterBroker("Broker");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return broker;
}

/**
 * Prints the Cloudlet objects.
 *
 * @param list list of Cloudlets
 */
private static void printCloudletList(List<Cloudlet> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    Cloudlet cloudlet;

    String indent = "    ";
    Log.printLine();
    Log.printLine("========== OUTPUT ==========");
    Log.printLine("Cloudlet ID" + indent + "STATUS" + indent
            + "Data center ID" + indent + "VM ID" + indent + "Time" + indent
            + "Start Time" + indent + "Finish Time");

    DecimalFormat dft = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cloudlet = list.get(i);
        Log.print(indent + cloudlet.getCloudletId() + indent + indent);

        if (cloudlet.getCloudletStatus() == Cloudlet.SUCCESS) {
            Log.print("SUCCESS");

            Log.printLine(indent + indent + cloudlet.getResourceId()
                    + indent + indent + indent + cloudlet.getVmId()
                    + indent + indent
                    + dft.format(cloudlet.getActualCPUTime()) + indent
                    + indent + dft.format(cloudlet.getExecStartTime())
                    + indent + indent
                    + dft.format(cloudlet.getFinishTime()));
        }
    }
}

}
```

I want to add a note, that the structure of this project is not constituted into packages. Here is an outline description of the project hierarchy :

```
/CloudAuction
/CloudAuction/src
/CloudAuction/src/main
/CloudAuction/src/test
/CloudAuction/src/test/java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/AuctionExample1.java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/AuctionExample2.java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/AuctionExample3.java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/AuctionExample4.java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/BidderBrokerFactory.java
/CloudAuction/src/test/java/org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction/BidderDatacenterFactory.java
/CloudAuction/target
/CloudAuction/pom.xml
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution to this problem, please ?

Comment: Just a note: it's a really bad idea to post someone's name and e-mail address (especially if it's not yours).

Comment: Fix your hierarchy of folders to make it match the hierarchy of pacages. Put unit-test classes in the test directory, and not production classes, which should go in main. Once done, if you still can't run the class, come back and tell us how you try to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

under the src folder you must have the package name represented as folders. In your code you have : org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples.auction as package name but you don't have the same folders in you src, the folder need to be like this :

```
src/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/auction/YourClass.java
```

Comment: Thank You for your helping, I figures out the solution by simply created a new project in which there are packages under the src folder. But I think, there are another one more simpler, which consist to build the project via pom.xml file by using Maven tool.